# No ATI HDMI Audio. Ubuntu 13.10. A10-6500k

Tags: drivers, sound, ati, 13.10, hdmi

I have tried so many things and can't get this to work. I am using the AMD A10-6500k on a ASRock FM2A88X-ITX+ Motherboard. I have installed multiple versions of the AMD Catalyst Propietary driver and no matter what I do I cannot get Ubuntu to recognize my sound device. Here is some relevant info.

aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

lsmod | grep '^snd'

```
snd_hda_codec_realtek    56599  1 
snd_hda_intel          48210  5 
snd_hda_codec         188852  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102033  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30095  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29433  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69141  19 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
```

lspci -vk | egrep -iA13 "audio"

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1150
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at ff740000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 780e
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=64
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more info please let me know. Thank You.

Comment: Close voters: This question has a good answer, there is no need to close it.

Answer (score 2):

OK so answering my own question here. I should have looked at this before I tried all the things I tried. On the ASRock FM2A88X-ITX+ the HDMI audio is disabled by default. That's it.

Comment: You should ask for your accounts to be merged in the contact us link below.